# How do I control multiple 4 pin LEDs with minimum GPIO pins?

Tags: microcontroller, led, circuit-design, integrated-circuit, 74hc595

I am using 42 four pin LEDs (common cathode) for my project, and I have to control them individually.

I know we can use "WS2812b" for more effective usage, but 4 pin is a requirement in my case.

I am using 74HC595 shift register to control 8 pins, but for controlling 42 LEDs I need 16 shift register, and not a good solution. Any idea/suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Use 2 Pcs HV5222PG-G, which is a 32-bit shift register ic. Or you can use any microcontroller to do so.

You will need 42+3 = 45 Pins in total.

Comment: HV5222PG-G is a rare IC. I checked online, but couldnt find one.

Comment: wait let me suggest yousome avaialable ic

Answer (score 2):

You want to multiplex your LED's.

This  http://lednique.com/display-technology/multiplexed-display/ (Simple introduction)
and this
https://www.instructables.com/Practical-Guide-to-LEDs-4-Matrix-Multiplexing/ (more in-depth)
are what you want to do.

It's not complex or unknown.  You just didn't know what to call it   ;)   You'll probably need some line drivers or (if you're cheap like me) a bunch of transistors because your CPU's I/O won't be able to directly handle the current.   The switches shown in the referenced links are, obviously, transistors or drivers....

Comment: I read about Charlieplexing and Multiplexing,
that works perfectly fine if I am working with 2 pin LED.
In 4 pin LEDs, that won`t be same case

This is circuit Diagram I am making, fell free to edit : https://www.tinkercad.com/things/jVj7lLlmIL4-daring-bruticus/editel?tenant=circuits

Comment: I can't open that schematic w/o creating an account, which I don't want to do right now.     Anyhow, not sure what you mean by the above - DO you think it's not possible to use 3-color (4 pin) LED's in a multiplexed scheme?   It's definitely possible.     Here's how you do it https://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/119179/RGBCube.png    Not a well drawn schematic, but the best I could find.    If this is gibberish and you want a better drawn one, let me know and I'll send you one of mine   ;)

Comment: Another, better drawn schematic  -  https://cdn.instructables.com/ORIG/FLX/20CM/J70QVLBP/FLX20CMJ70QVLBP.png?fit=bounds&frame=1&height=1024&width=1024

Comment: These schematics seems to be very useful, Thanks buddy!!

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to mention [Charlieplexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlieplexing), which exploits the directionality of diodes and the ability for microcontrollers to both source and sink current to efficiently multiplex an array of LEDs.

I'm not sure exactly how well it will work with your common cathode RGB LEDs but it might be worth giving a try along with other methods

Comment: I read about Charlieplexing and Multiplexing,
that works perfectly fine if I am working with 2 pin LED.
In 4 pin LEDs, that won`t be same case

This is circuit Diagram I am making, fell free to edit : https://www.tinkercad.com/things/jVj7lLlmIL4-daring-bruticus/editel?tenant=circuits

Comment: The principles behind Charlieplexing should be applicable to four pin LEDs. Model the common cathode LEDs according to their internal connections. The link you sent requires an account so I can't see or edit.